# Python - which is the better way of calling superclass' method?

Tags: python, oop, class

All the while I have been using:

```
SuperClass.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

My reason is that this shows explicitly which superclass is used, especially in the case of multiple inheritance.

However, other codes I came across use

```
super(MyClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

instead.

This could become ambigious when it's used in:

```
class MyClass(SuperClass1, SuperClass2):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) #which SuperClass is being used?
```

I would like to know why this form of calling is widely adopted? Any advantage at all?

Answer (score 21):

The reason that `super` is prefereable for modern (*new style*) classes is that it allows *cooperative* multiple inheritance. Here's an example.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def display(self):
...         print "In Foo"
... 
>>> class Foo2(Foo):
...     def display(self):
...         print "In Foo2"
...         super(Foo2, self).display()
...         print "Back in Foo2"
... 
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     def display(self):
...         print "In Bar"
...         super(Bar, self).display()
...         print "Back in Bar"
... 
>>> class FooBar(Foo2, Bar):
...     pass
... 
>>> FooBar().display()
In Foo2
In Bar
In Foo
Back in Bar
Back in Foo2
>>> class BarFoo(Bar, Foo2):
...     pass
... 
>>> BarFoo().display()
In Bar
In Foo2
In Foo
Back in Foo2
Back in Bar
```

Note that I didn't do anything to change the `display` method on the superclasses but I got different `display` methods on the subclasses by changing the order in which I arranged the superclasses. `BarFoo` and `FooBar` have different methods. This is because they have different *Method Resolution Orders*

```
>>> BarFoo.__mro__
(<class '__main__.BarFoo'>, <class '__main__.Bar'>, <class '__main__.Foo2'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> FooBar.__mro__
(<class '__main__.FooBar'>, <class '__main__.Foo2'>, <class '__main__.Bar'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <type 'object'>)
```

This means that `super` resolves to a different class for each subclass that it's called in. This allows for each overriding method to change a small part of what's going on and still let every other superclass contribute to the method call as long as they're willing to play nicely.

Answer (score 6):

For new style classes which inherit from `object`, `super` is used.

The `__mro__` (method resolution order) attribute of the *type* lists the method resolution search order used by `super`.

```
>>> class X(object):
    pass

>>> class Y(object):
    pass

>>> class Z(X, Y):
    pass

>>> Z.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Z'>, <class '__main__.X'>, <class '__main__.Y'>, <type 'object'>)
```

This specifies the ordering for Z. Since it is `Z(X, Y)`, `X` is first in the hierarchy. Had it been `Z(Y, X)`, `Y` would have preceded over `X`.

For old style classes, `SuperClass.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` is used.

UPDATE:

For your question as to which `SuperClass` is being used.

```
>>> class First(object):
    pass

>>> class Second(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'Second __init__ called'

>>> class MInherit(First, Second):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MInherit, self).__init__()

>>> i = MInherit()
Second __init__ called
```

First, `First` will be checked to see if it has an `__init__`, since `First` comes first in the MRO. Since in this case 'First' doesn't have an `__init__`, so `Second` is called. Had there been an `__init__` in `First`, only that would have been called.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the good answers already posted, here is some additional info:

- Old-style classes (those that don't derive from object) have a depth-first method resolution order.  Old-style classes call their super classes in the way that you are used to.
- New-style classes (those that do derive from object) have a more complicated method resolution order.  At the highest level it is akin to breadth first, but is more complex than that.  See this [page](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) for an excellent explanation.  Using "super()" allows new style classes to follow this method resolution order.
- If you are using new-style classes, you can still use the old-style of calling super classes and your code will still work.  The differences only become apparent for more complicated multiple-inheritance patterns.