# No constructor overloading in Python - Disadvantage?

Tags: python

I was going through DiveIntoPython and came across this:

> Java and Powerbuilder support function overloading by argument list,
>   i.e. one class can have multiple methods with the same name but a
>   different number of arguments, or arguments of different types. Other
>   languages (most notably PL/SQL) even support function overloading by
>   argument name; i.e. one class can have multiple methods with the same
>   name and the same number of arguments of the same type but different
>   argument names. Python supports neither of these; it has no form of
>   function overloading whatsoever. Methods are defined solely by their
>   name, and there can be only one method per class with a given name. So
>   if a descendant class has an `__init__` method, it always overrides the
>   ancestor `__init__` method, even if the descendant defines it with a
>   different argument list. And the same rule applies to any other
>   method.

Isn't this a major disadvantage that a subclass's `__init__` method will *always* override a superclass's `__init__` method? So if I'm initializing some variables and calling some functions in a class `class1`'s `__init__`, then I derive a subclass `class2(class1)` of it, I'd have to reinitialize all of `class1`'s variables and call those functions in `class2`'s `__init__`?

I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding all this, so it'd be great if someone clarifies this up.

Answer (score 14):

You're right that defining `__init__` in a subclass overrides the superclass's `__init__`, but you can always use `super(CurrentClass, self).__init__` to call the superclass's constructor from the subclass. So, you don't have to "manually" duplicate the superclass's initialization work.

As a side note, even though Python doesn't support method overloading, it supports default arguments (in addition to optional arguments via `*args` and `**kwargs`), which means you can easily emulate the behavior of overloaded functions by simply accepting different subsets of arguments in your function/method implementation.

Comment: And if you use the `*args` / `**kwdargs**` method to do some dispatch to specific functions, then you realise it doesn't actually hurt to have the functions named differently anyway :)

Comment: @tom of course I did that, is super a new word? I'm trying at http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~kwalsh/python/ since I don't have python in this machine

Comment: `super` was added in Python 2.2 (a while ago). The version of Python you're using must be older than that.

Comment: @tom `super` will not work in all cases, it must be a new style class, this is why I was getting the error. `BaseClass.__init__(self)` will work. Test cases: [Direct call](http://ideone.com/IJperH), [failed super call](http://ideone.com/jLAQ8b), [succeed super call in new style class](http://ideone.com/zEV8PX), [Direct call in new style class](http://ideone.com/Ad3oxL)

Comment: "you can easily emulate the behavior of overloaded functions by simply accepting different subsets of arguments in your function/method implementation." But please be responsible. Don't try to jam wildly different function signatures into a single function.

Answer (score 2):

> So if I'm initializing some variables and calling some functions in a class class1's `__init__`, then I derive a subclass class2(class1) of it, I'd have to reinitialize all of class1's variables and call those functions in class2's `__init__`?

No. You just have to call the superclass's `__init__()`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805066/how-to-call-a-parent-classs-method-from-child-class-in-python), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300738/python-which-is-the-better-way-of-calling-superclass-method), you can find how to do it.