# Why do base classes in Python need to extend object?

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm looking for a clear explanation of why my base classes must extend `object` if I want to use `super`

```
# Without extending object, this code will fail with 
# TypeError: must be type, not classobj
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print "Called A.__init__"

class AChild(A):
  def __init__(self):
    super(AChild, self).__init__()
    print "Called AChild.__init__"

AChild()
```

This works as expected, but if you remove `object` it throws the exception mentioned. I'm using Python 2.7.8. Feel free to link me to any related questions, but I didn't find a good answer with a quick search

Answer (score 1):

It's because by extending `object` you are using new style classes which are required to support the use of `super`, which was added alongside the introduction of new style classes to Python.

According to the information in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304848/1219006), old style classes had a simple depth-first method resolution order so there was no need for this function, and thats probably why it wasn
t included then. However upon adding multiple inheritance, `super` is now the recommended way to call a superclass because of the more complicated MRO.

Comment: And to add confusion, Python3 no longer requires `(object)` - because all class are now 'new style'.

Comment: @hpaulj Good point but not that confusing cause it still works anyway if you do subclass it

Comment: `super` is not just a new way to access a super class. It's meant for implementing cooperative inheritance, meaning all classes in the hierarchy where `super` is used must be written to support the use of `super` in any ancester/class in the hierarchy. It's important to understand the implications of using `super` before using it.

Comment: @chepner I was talking about why there was not an equivalent `super` for old style classes beforehand and maybe that could have predicted these additions to the language and been forward compatible.